# Stencil e2e tests failing on server

Tags: npm, puppeteer, e2e-testing, stenciljs

I have a stenciljs project with unit and e2e tests that works perfectly locally but fails on server with the given error:

> Failed to launch chrome! spawn
>              /builds/header/node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium/linux-588429/chrome-linux/chrome
>              ENOENT TROUBLESHOOTING:
>              https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/troubleshooting.md
>              Error: Failed to launch chrome! spawn
>              /builds/header/node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium/linux-588429/chrome-linux/chrome
>              ENOENT TROUBLESHOOTING:
>              https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/troubleshooting.md
>              at onClose
>              (/builds/header/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/Launcher.js:333:14)
>              at ChildProcess.helper.addEventListener.error
>              (/builds/header/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/Launcher.js:324:64)
>              at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:182:13) at
>              Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit
>              (internal/child_process.js:238:12) at onErrorNT
>              (internal/child_process.js:407:16) at process._tickCallback
>              (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)

package.json:

```
...
"scripts": {
  ...
  "e2e": "stencil test --e2e",
  ...
},
,
"dependencies": {
  "@stencil/core": "^0.15.2",
  "@stencil/sass": "^0.1.1",
  "ionicons": "^4.4.6"
},
"devDependencies": {
  "@stencil/dev-server": "0.0.18",
  "@stencil/utils": "latest",
  "@types/jest": "23.3.4",
  "@types/node": "10.5.3",
  "@types/puppeteer": "1.6.0",
  "jest": "23.5.0",
  "license-checker": "^24.0.1",
  "mocky": "^0.1.11",
  "npm-run-all": "^4.1.5",
  "pixelmatch": "4.0.2",
  "puppeteer": "1.7.0",
  "rollup-plugin-node-builtins": "^2.1.2",
  "rollup-plugin-node-globals": "^1.4.0",
  "workbox-build": "3.4.1"
}
```

The build is being run using gitlab runner, and when I searched for a solution to this I found that the newer version of puppeteer (v1.8.0) is the one having this problem so I fixed it at 1.7.0 in my package.josn but it's being updating during the execution of the tests:

> stencil test --e2e

[28:43.7]  Please wait while required dependencies are updated. This may
           take a few moments and will only be required for the initial
           run.
[28:43.7]  installing dependencies: jest-cli, @types/puppeteer, jest, puppeteer
           ...
npm WARN deprecated kleur@2.0.2: Please upgrade to kleur@3 or migrate to 'ansi-colors' if you prefer the old syntax. Visit [https://github.com/lukeed/kleur/releases/tag/v3.0.0\](https://github.com/lukeed/kleur/releases/tag/v3.0.0%5C) for migration path(s).

> puppeteer@1.8.0 install /builds/header/node_modules/puppeteer
>   node install.js

Chromium downloaded to /builds/header/node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium/linux-588429

- jest@23.6.0
- jest-cli@23.6.0
- puppeteer@1.8.0
- @types/puppeteer@1.11.2
  added 1 package, removed 17 packages, updated 23 packages and moved 23 packages in 50.353s
  [29:34.7]  installing dependencies finished in 51.00 s